# Program to create a string from two given strings by concatenating the characters that are not contained by both strings

Tags: python

> 14. Write a Python program to create a string from two given strings by concatenating the characters that are not contained by both strings. The characters from the 1st string should appear before the characters from the 2nd string. Return the resulting string.
>       Sample input: ‘0abcxyz’, ‘abcxyz1’
>       Expected Output: ‘01’

I have already got the results but would like to learn if there is a better way to achieve the same results.'''

```
var14_1, var14_2 = '0abcxyz', 'abcxyz1'
def concat(var14_1,var14_2):
    res = []
    [res.append(s) for s in var14_1 if s not in var14_2]
    [res.append(s) for s in var14_2 if s not in var14_1]
    print(''.join(res))

concat(var14_1,var14_2)
```

The above code is returning the results as 01 which is as 
expected. However I would like to know if there is any other way 
to arrive at this solution without having to use "for loop" 
twice. Your feedback will immensely help in improving my python skills. Thanks in advance!

Comment: using list comprehensions `[ ]` to run `res.append()` doesn't look nice. It would be nicer to use normal `for`-loop. OR create to lists `r1 = [ s for ...  ]` and `r2 = [ s for ...]` and later create one list `res = r1 + r2`

Answer (score 5):

It would be nicer to not use list comprehensions only to run many times `res.append()`

```
var14_1, var14_2 = '0abcxyz', 'abcxyz1'

r1 = [s for s in var14_1 if s not in var14_2]
r2 = [s for s in var14_2 if s not in var14_1]
res = r1 + r2

print(''.join(res))
```

---

To use one `for` loop you could convert strings to sets and get common chars

```
common = set('0abcxyz') & set('abcxyz1')
```

and then you can use one `for` with concatenated strings `var14_1 + var14_2`

```
common = set('0abcxyz') & set('abcxyz1')

res = [s for s in var14_1 + var14_2 if s not in common]

print(''.join(res))
```

Comment: Thanks @furas for responses. Really Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. 
@furas pointed out you don't need list() while using set, so updated for that.

```
var14_1, var14_2 = '0abcxyz', 'abcxyz1'
def concat(first, second):
    return ''.join(set(first).symmetric_difference(set(second)))

print(concat(var14_1, var14_2))
```

taking a set of an object creates an unordered collection of unique elements.

```
set()
```

has a function called symmetric_difference() which allows you to find the symmetric difference between two sets.

Comment: What if the variables were swapped, i.e. `var14_1 = 'abxyz1' and var14_2 = '0abcxyz'?` Will this give the desired output `10`?

Comment: it doesn't work if vars are `'1abcxyz', 'abcxyz0'` which should give `'10'` but you get `'01'`

Comment: Updated by removing sorted(). this should work now @furas

Comment: problem can be bigger because `set()` doesn't have to keep order and when I run your new code then sometimes I get `{'0','1'}` but sometimes it gives me `{'1','0'}`

Comment: Updated to join the sets into a string as OP requested. Let me know if you're getting the same issue :)